# AWS after deploying I found error that webpage not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, html, webdeploy, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I received this error after depolyment when I run the code on Amazon web server in web.xml mapping is done:

> This newaws.t3wxtj3ywg.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com page can't be found

[image: See screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As your information provided is insufficient, we can only give a try on what's going on to your website.

Here are some possible issues :

1. Incorrect DNS configuration

> Did you point your DNS to AWS?

2. Incorrect firewall configuration

Please provide more information.